# Get current google shared drive Id in Google Workspace Add on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I am creating a Google workspace addon integrating with Google shared drive. I am trying to get the current shared drive id in the homePageTrigger run function (not the onItemsSelectedTrigger). The event object does not seem to have the drive information unless I select a folder/file within the drive. Is it possible to get the drive Id, drive name when the add on is shown?